# Conditionally deleting rows in a matrix

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I  have a 22x14 Matrix. Some of the entries in the matrix are '-1', signifying missing data.

1. I'd like to be able to delete a Row whose j<sup>th</sup> entry is '-1'
2. I'd like to be able to delete a Row whose any entry is '-1'

I've been looking for this here and an wolfram but all I've seen are commands that enable one to drop a particular row or column unconditionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `DeleteCases` for this, for example if `table` is your data then for the first case you could do

```
DeleteCases[table, a_/;a[[j]]===-1]
```

where `j` is the index you want to check for, and for the second case

```
DeleteCases[table, a_ /; MemberQ[a, -1]]
```

Other functions you could use for selecting elements from lists based on patterns or selection criteria are `Cases` and `Select`.